# how to do onclick event on a view of fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and inside oncreateview I have create a view and want to close that view on click event but somehow its not working.

This is the code I tried adding dismiss in onViewCreated but it doesn't work though dismiss on close_button click works perfectly fine

but the view doesn't dismiss on click of view.

Any help would be great thanks

```
public class AudioDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public AudioDialog() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @NonNull
    public static AudioDialog newInstance(boolean isDvAvailable, boolean isCcAvailable) {
        AudioDialog fragment = new AudioDialog();

        fragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.VideoFragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_dialog, container, false);

    }


 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
        view.findViewById(R.id.close_button).setOnClickListener(v -> this.dismiss());

// This view Dismiss seems not to work
        view.setOnClickListener(v -> this.dismiss());

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean close that view? What view are you refering?

Comment: In a fragment we create a view and I want to dismiss that view on a click event


@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_dialog, container, false);

view.setOnClickListener(v -> dismiss());
        return view;

    }

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between a `View` and `Fragment`. To better understand your question, please add more of your code to your question.